# How to see MQTT data in AWS IOT and Azure IOT HUB

Tags: azure-iot-hub, aws-iot

I have a MQTT client which publish data (topic) to "AWS IOT" and "Azure IOT HUB".

To see the data into "Azure IOT HUB", I am using "DeviceExplorer":
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer

I want to know?

```
For Azure IOT HUB:
- How I can see the same data in azure portal?

For AWS IOT:
- Is there any similar tool for AWS IOT?
- How I can see the same in AWS portal? (I thought it should be "CloudWatch", but not sure how to use it?)
```

Any links and reference will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Azure portal:

There is no built-in feature to see a telemetry data in the Azure IoT Hub portal. However, the following Azure apps can help you:

- [Azure IoT Central](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-central/)
- [Time Series Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/time-series-insights/)
- [EventHubTrigger Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot)

In the case of using Visual Studio:

[Cloud Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.CloudExplorerForVS)

Answer (score 0):

**For Azure IOT HUB:**

To see the data in the Azure portal, you can go to the "IoT Hub" page and click on the "Monitor" tab. From there, you can view the real-time telemetry data and events from your devices. You can also use the "Data Explorer" feature to view and query your device data.

**For AWS IoT:**

There is no specific tool similar to Device Explorer for AWS IoT. However, you can use the AWS IoT console to view and monitor your device data.
To view the data in the AWS portal, you can go to the "AWS IoT" page and click on the "Test" tab. From there, you can subscribe to a topic and view the real-time data published by your devices. Alternatively, you can use the "CloudWatch" service to view and monitor your device data. To do this, you can create a "Rule" that forwards your device data to CloudWatch, and then use the CloudWatch console to view the data. You can also use the CloudWatch API to access and query your device data.